# I can not setup Microsoft office 2010

Tags: microsoft-office-2010

---

### Setup Errors

Setup is unable to proceed due to the following error(s):
Microsoft Office 2010 does not support upgrading from a prerelease version of Microsoft Office 2010. You must first uninstall any prerelease versions of Microsoft Office 2010 products and associated technologies.

### Correct the issue(s) listed above and re-run setup.

### OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search of Microsoft support gives this answer, but you have to be comfortable making registry changes to use it.

N.B. Although the answer refers to Office 2007, it is also valid for 2010

http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officeinstall/thread/867c5a9f-5369-4062-a60c-25ca9168fb31

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried to follow the error message's advice and uninstall the pre-release version of Office you have installed?

This can be Alpha, Beta or Release Candidate, you need to uninstall them all.

Comment: i unstall its but i get error again